# Cron job to start the VM instance in Google cloud compute engine

Tags: cron, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have an instance named `instance-1` in my compute engine. I want to start this VM instance through my cron job. Is it possible ? I know I can use googleapis to start the VM instance but I can't figure out how to do it. Should I write a java application to start my VM instance with the use of API and then invoke this application by `cron.yaml` url field, or is there any other better way.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the [instances.start API method](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/start). There is an example for java, but also for c#, go, node.js, php, python and ruby. For java, you just need to install the [Java client library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/compute/v1) and replace the project, zone and instance name in the example.